# Graph theory - Shortest closed walk is a cycle?

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

So I'm trying to prove the lemma:
"The shortest positive length closed walk through a vertex is a cycle."

Defs: A closed walk is a walk that begins and ends at the same vertex. A cycle is a positive length closed walk whose vertices are distinct except for the beginning and end vertices.

So far I have:

Proof: If there is a closed walk from u to v, then there must be a positive minimum length walk w, from u to v. We claim w is a cycle.
To prove this claim, suppose to the contrary that the shortest positive length closed walk through a vertex is not a cycle. Meaning some vertex (x) is not repeated within this closed walk u to v and there is another vertex (y),

```
 w = e (merge x) f (merge y) g
```

for some walks e, f, g where f is positive.
If we delete f then.. (this is where I am stuck.)

I'm doing this proof based off another, to which book said they would be essentially the same but I'm not sure. Where am I going wrong?
Other proof:

[image: Other Lemma]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to be clear here, we first note that all walks here have to be *non-lazy* and also be *nonbacktracking* as in if $W=x_1x_2\ldots x_r$ then $x_j \not \in \{x_{j+1},x_{j+2}\}$ for all $j$. Otherwise a walk that traverses an edge in each direction (or stays at the same vertex) is closed but is not a cycle.

Next, suppose $G$ is a path $P=u_0\ldots u_r$ with $r+1$ vertices plus a cycle $C$ that intersects $P$ at precisely $u_r$. Then the shortest closed non-lazy nonbacktracking walk in $G$ *that contains the vertex $u_0$* is **not** a cycle, you need to walk from $u_0$ to $u_r$, go around the cycle $C$, and then come back to $u_0$. The shortest walk in $G$ *overall* is a cycle though; in fact it is $C$. This shortest walk does not contain $u_0$.

> Anyway, let $G$ be a graph. Then the shortest closed non-lazy nonbacktracking walk in $G$, if such a walk exists, is a cycle.

Proof Sketch [make sure you see each step]: Let $W = x_0x_1x_2\ldots x_t$ be a shortest-length closed nonbacktracking walk. Then by the fact that $W$ is closed $x_0=x_t$. Suppose that $W$ is not a cycle. Then there are integers $i'$ and $j'$; $i'<j'$ s.t. $j'-i' < t$, and $x_{i'}=x_{j'}$. Then $W'=x_{i'}x_{i'+1}\ldots x_{j'}$ [i.e., $W$ minus the first $i'-1$ vertices and the last $t-j'$ vertices of $W$] is a closed walk and is shorter than $W$. Contradiction.

Comment: I almost understand. So you say there are integers i' <  j'    s.t.  j' - i' < t. These are just lengths, right? Then you say x<sub>i'<sub> = x<sub>j'<sub>. I thought we just supposed W wasn't a cycle? Or was this portion showing it was a closed walk? I guess I'm not sure how you constructed W'.

Comment: We are assuming that $W$ is not a cycle and then arriving at a contradiction that it is the shortest [non-lazy non-backtracking] walk. If you have such a walk $W$ that is not a cycle then at some point in $W$ you will visit some vertex twice where this vertex is not the starting/ending vertex $x_0=x_t$. Put another way there is some such $i',j'$ s.t. $x_{i'} = x_{j'}$. Then the walk $W'$ formed from cutting off the first $i'-1$ steps and the last $t-j'$ steps of $W$ is closed and is strictly shorter, giving a contradiction that $W$ was the shortest such walk.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I appreciate your help!